# What does capital letter I mean in this formulas?

Tags: notation, indicator-function

Hello I don't understand meaning of the symbol represented by a capital letter "I" in the formulas below.
There is [a link](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/SII-2-3-A8-Zhu.pdf) to the paper with the formulas.

[image: Screen shot from the paper with the symbol I don't understand.]

At the beginning I thought it mean "where c is not equal to the result of classifier T(m)", however in step (d) there is a multiplication symbol before it, so it probably mean that "I" should "return" a value.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's the indicator function! It takes value 1 if the condition inside the brackets is met, 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

To add to stochazesthai correct answer.

In your examples the first usage indicates 1 in the case where the prediction of the mth tree does not equal the actual class. If it not equal then 1 is "returned" and so will affect the error term via the weight.